# How to test plastic for ESD properties?

Tags: esd, testing

I'd like to make myself a cheap soldering / inspection station by taking an acetal plastic slab and mounting a linear rail to it for attaching a USB microscope.  However, I want to first ensure that the slab is either anti-static or conductive enough that grounding it will actually prevent charge buildup.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge_materials), it looks like the following properties are the ones I should think about:

> Insulative
>
> Insulative materials prevent or limit the flow of electrons across their surface or through their volume. Insulative materials have a
> high electrical resistance and are difficult to ground, thus are not
> ESD materials. Static charges remain in place on these materials for a
> very long time.
>
> Anti-Static
>
> Anti-static materials are generally referred to as any material which inhibits triboelectric charging. This kind of charging is the
> buildup of an electric charge by the rubbing or contact with another
> material. One type of anti-static packaging material is commonly
> referred to as Pink Poly. It is a clear pink (hot pink) polyethylene
> that is available as a film for bags, bubble pack, or foam.
>
> Dissipative
>
> Dissipative materials allow the charges to flow to ground more slowly in a more controlled manner than with conductive materials.
>
> Conductive
>
> Conductive materials have a low electrical resistance, thus electrons flow easily across the surface or through these materials.
> Charges go to ground or to another conductive object that the material
> contacts.

Clearly, I want to avoid the acetal I have if it's insulative.  I assume that to determine if it's anti-static, I need to rub another material against it to see if one or the other becomes charged (uh... hold one of the materials next to my kid's head afterward?  LOL).  For the others, it sounds like I have to sandwich the plate between two metal bars and then measure resistance, or I have to insert probes and pass current through them, while measuring via two other probes.

I read that there is acetal ESD plastic, but I don't want to assume that all acetal is naturally ESD compatible.  It sounds like such a thing isn't likely, as conductive fibers probably need to be added during production.

Does anyone know of any other ways to tell if my plastic is safe as an ESD work surface?

Comment: For a start, what does your multimeter say?

Comment: I am not at home so I don't have the plastic with me.  However, I looked into this online and it sounds like a two point test with a multimeter isn't an accurate way to do it -- apparently you have to use the four point test...

Comment: I'm interested in this too. I bought anti-static gloves, and I assumed I'll be able to measure it's resistance. But no luck measuring it with my multimeter (capable of measuring up to 50 MΩ). How do I know if it's actually anti-static?